# Please tell me how to get a push/notification when the phone is locked

Tags: android, push-notification, push, screen, light

Please help.
When the phone screen is off (locked), at this time Android phones can’t receive push notifications.

Please tell me how to get a push/notification when the phone is locked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are getting notification data in data payload or notification payload. Try Sending the notification data in data payload.